# How can I write a regular expression match for a string that must contain the following characters: thankYou.sjs?donate_page

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex query for a Google Analytics goal.  The goal url must contain:

thankYou.sjs?donate_page

However, there are many urls than can render this string, all with other modifiers that I don't care about.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Just the string itself will work.  If you want *only* this string, just use the start/end of string zero-width assertions:

```
^thankYou\.sjs\?donate_path$
```

Comment: yeah, but the problem is that string does not start with thankYou.sjs

Comment: give me an example input and output

Comment: I think I figured it out with this query:   ^thankYou\.sjs\?donate_page.*    Please let know if this works. I need the query to return only pages containing the above string.

Answer (score 0):

@ExplosionPills: I think you forgot about the special meaning of the question mark.
If you don't escape it, your expression:

```
^thankYou.sjs?donate_path$
```

Would match

```
thankYou.sjsdonate_path
```

or

```
thankYou.sjdonate_path
```

Not to mention the special meaning of dot.

So I guess something like this should work:

```
thankYou\.sjs\?donate_path
```

Furthermore if it's possible that the donate_path is not the first in the query string you can use this:

```
thankYou\.sjs\?([^&]*&)*donate_path
```